# Program runs on Win 7, but not on Win 8

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, windows-7

I have a program I've written on Windows 7 (64-bit) that compiles and runs correctly on my computer.

But on other computers (specifically on Windows 8 (64-bit)) the program does not run. When I try to run it it says that my program has stopped working, it crashes.

I should add, both computers have .Net installed at version 4.5.

But, if I delete all the components that I've added onto my form (I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express) it runs just fine. But I have to delete all of the components. Deleting only some of them doesn't work.

Has anyone heard of this happening?

Comment: Use a debugger or DebugDiag or write an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException to diagnose the crash.

Comment: "Has anyone heard of this?" is not a question that can be answered here. I'm sure someone somewhere has heard of this, but you're asking a vague, general question. There is no detail in your question that would allow us to even speculate on what is causing the problem, and we don't do speculation and "list of possible causes for a very broad, vague problem" here.

Comment: Thankfully I did get information to help me solve the problem, which was the idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Hans, I hadn't heard of the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Unhandled exception before.

My actual problem was that I didn't have the VisualBasic things installed on the Windows 8 computer, and I was trying to use them. Removing the references of that from my program fixed the program.

The actual code I used to find the problem (In Program.cs):

```
static void Main()
    {
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);
     (...)   
    }
static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
        Console.WriteLine("MyHandler caught : " + e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("Runtime terminating: {0}", args.IsTerminating);
        MessageBox.Show("Handler caught: " + e.Message + "\nRuntime terminating: " + args.IsTerminating);
    }
```