# Desktop program runs in Win 7 but not in Win 8

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I have the same problem as Elec0 in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18645026/2876276. My program developed in VS 2012 for Desktop on a Win 7 machine, using .Net 4.5 and WPF won't run on a Win 8 machine. I tried the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException solution (in MainWindow.xaml.cs) but the program still crashes on the Win 8 machine without reporting an error.

Elec0 reported the problem was that he didn't have the "VisualBasic things" on his Win 8 machine. What were these things, or the equivalent in C#?

Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

DebugDiag reports:

```
In MyProgram__PID__1072__Date__10_13_2013__Time_06_21_18PM__19__Second_Chance_Exception_C000041D.dmp the assembly instruction at 0x00000000 which does not correspond to any known native module in the process has caused a CLR Exception on thread 0 with the following error information:

    Type:   NOT_FOUND 
    Message:   NOT_FOUND 
...
.NET Call Stack



Function 
MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, Int32) 
MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, Int32) 
MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef) 
MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef) 


Full Call Stack



Function     Arg 1     Arg 2     Arg 3     Arg 4   Source 
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+68     00000041`aaf894b8     00000041`aaf893f8     00000041`ad3580a8     00000041`aaf8a800    
clr!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly+28b     00000000`00000000     000007fa`641092d8     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000001    
clr!IL_Rethrow+98     000007fa`6095e770     00000041`000000f1     00000041`aaffcc48     00000041`aaf8a100    
PresentationCore_ni+c9c794     00000041`aafffdf0     000007fa`6095e770     00000041`aaffcbb0     00000041`aafffdf0    
clr!ExceptionTracker::CallHandler+c5     00000041`aaffcbb0     000007fa`614ec770     00000041`aaf8c000     00000041`aaffcc48    
clr!ExceptionTracker::CallCatchHandler+7c     00000041`aaf8c000     00000041`aaf899f0     00000041`aaf8b230     00000000`00000002    
clr!ProcessCLRException+2e2     00000041`aaf8b500     00000041`aaf8c000     00000000`00000000     00000041`aaf899f0
```

I also have a WER from Windows log with details of modules loaded.

Comment: You'll need to debug it.  Use the DebugDiag tool if necessary.

Comment: Check up windows logs, there should be some error message from .NET Runtime.

Comment: Try a comment asking for clarification on the answer you quote.

Comment: The exception you get is _0xC000041D An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback_ and there is a bug in MSHTML described in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2856748 resulting in that exception on Windows 8. Probably not relevant but if you are using MSHTML and have managed not to patch IE 10 then perhaps this is your issue?

Comment: I've got latest optional updates and problem persists. I've now got additional reports from DebugDiag referring to Kernelbase.dll : In MyProgram__PID__2672__Date__10_14_2013__Time_08_46_04AM__316__First chance exception 0X04242420.dmp the assembly instruction at KERNELBASE!RaiseException+68 in C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused an unknown exception (0x04242420) on thread 0